# session with multiple queries: does the database get hit multiple times?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I have a session with 10 select queries in it.  When I commit the session, do all 10 queries get sent over as a single request, or are there 10 database round trips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With NHibernate, you can use Future, them it can be done in just one round trip (if you database driver supports this).

```
Session.QueryOver<Food>().Where(x => x.IsGood).Future<Food>();
Session.QueryOver<Product>().Where(x => x.IsCheap).Future<Product>();
```

Both will be executed in only on round trip to DB.

More info about Future [here](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/01/nhibernate-and-future-queries/) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures)

Comment: I agree with @Rafael here.  It depends on how you are querying the data in NHibernate.  If you use `Futures` it does the selects in one round trip otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: Also: Commits will be batched based on settings.  So if your session has a batch-size of 10, and you insert/update/delete 25 items you'll have 3 round-trips for data modification any selects you do.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, there will be 10 round trips. Updates to model objects can be left to the commit, but not selects. This is because the results of a select must be available immediately after the query returns. In fact, if there's any lazy loading going on, the session must remain open to the lazy fields can be populated by subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

A session is not committed, but transactions are. A session is a connection wrapper to the database (and in terms of NHibernate it does even more) and should be short living. When you issue a read or write operation via NHibernate, it of course gets send to the database since you need a sync result. 
When a write operation is executed from code, it is also sent to the db immediately. If this operation is committed in the end, depends on if it is executed in a transaction.

Sessions can be closed after every operation if you like. Usually databases support connection pooling and retrieving a new session for new operations is not expensive.